# Doctrine Single Table Inheritance extends from Mapped Superclass

Tags: symfony, inheritance, doctrine

What i want to do is to extend a single table inheritance class from a mapped superclass, but when i try to update the scheme i go following error:

> [Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\SchemaException]
>   An index with name 'uniq_efe84ad134ecb4e6' was already defined on table 'article_article'.

My Hierarchy:

Content (mappedSuperClass) <- Article (SingleTableInheritance) <- MyArticle

Classes:

```
abstract class Content
{
    protected $id;

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}

class Article extends Content
{

}

class MyArticle extends Article
{

}
```

Mappings:

```
Content:
    type: mappedSuperclass
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO


Article:
    type: entity
    table: article_article
    inheritanceType: SINGLE_TABLE
    discriminatorColumn:
        name: discr
        type: string
    discriminatorMap:
        article: Article
        my_article: MyArticle

MyArticle:
    type: entity
```

Whats wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is on the mappedSuperclass. The Content class has a **oneToOne** relationship, that is not in the example above, because i try to make it more abstract.

```
Content:
    # ...
    oneToOne:
        route:
            targetEntity: Route
```

It seems like doctrine try to add the unique key again for the extended class. I don't know if that is restriction to the mappedSuperclass or just a bug, but i solved it by **changing the oneToOne relationship into a manyToOne**, since it's nearly the same, but without a unique constraint.

```
Content:
    # ...
    manyToOne:
        route:
            targetEntity: Route
```